# Determine ranking with single mysql query

Tags: mysql

I am selecting a set of items from my table and determine their ranking to display this on my page, my code for selecting the items:

```
<?
$attra_query=mysqli_query($link, "select * from table WHERE category ='4'");
if(mysqli_num_rows($attra_query)>
0){
while($attra_data=mysqli_fetch_array($attra_query,1)){
?>
```

In the while loop I determine the ranking for each of those items like so:

```
SELECT COUNT(mi.location) + 1 rank
     FROM table m
LEFT JOIN (
     SELECT id,location,country, ROUND(COALESCE(total_rating/total_rating_amount,0),10) rating_per_vote
       FROM table WHERE category = '4'
          ) mi
       ON mi.location = m.location
       AND mi.country = m.country

      AND mi.rating_per_vote > ROUND(COALESCE(m.total_rating/m.total_rating_amount,0),10)
    WHERE m.id = '$attra_id';
```

I figure this is highly inefficient, is there a way to combine the 2 queries into a single one so I don't have to run the ranking query for each item separately ?

//EDIT
Sample data:

`id | location | country | category | total_rating | total_rating_amount
 1    berlin      DE         4           12               2

 2    munich      DE         4           9                1`

Vote system is 1-10 points, for the sample data `berlin` has received a total rating of 12 with 2 votes, `munich` has received a rating of 9 with 1 vote, so `berlin` would have a rating of 6/10 and `munich` a rating of 9/10 and therefore should be ranked #1

Comment: Can you represent table's schemas and example of their data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(m.id) rank, m.id
     FROM 
     (SELECT * FROM table WHERE category = '4') m
     LEFT JOIN (
     SELECT id,location,country, ROUND(COALESCE(total_rating/total_rating_amount,0),10) rating_per_vote
       FROM table WHERE category = '4'
          ) mi
       ON (mi.location = m.location
       AND mi.country = m.country
       AND mi.rating_per_vote > ROUND(COALESCE(m.total_rating/m.total_rating_amount,0),10))
       OR mi.id=m.id
GROUP BY m.id
```

This should do I suppose. I don't know if this is the best possible solution.

Comment: This somewhat seems to work, the rankings show up, but I can't get any other data from the table anymore with `while($attra_data=mysqli_fetch_array($attra_query,1)){` and then `$attra_data['location']` for example is empty ? Something I have to do different now ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, you can do the ranking using variables.  It is a bit hard to tell what you want to rank by from your query, but it would be something like this:

```
select t.*, (@rn := @rn + 1) as ranking
from table t cross join
     (select @rn := 0) vars
where category = '4'
order by rating_per_vote;
```

If you provide sample data and desired results, it would be possible to refine this solution.

Comment: I've added some sample data to my initial question now, thanks.